# Need OnCalcFields to be fired on all Rows in dataset Not only just rows visible in DBGrid delphi

Tags: delphi, aggregate, dbgrid

I am using Delphi XE5 and FireDAC.

I have a calculated field (Price_Each) and an aggregate field (Total_Price) in a dataset. The aggregate field sums the values of the Calculated Field (Price_Each).

The Dataset is displayed in a Dbgrid, and as there are many rows, some rows of the dataset are outside the Grid view window and need to be scrolled into view.

The issue I am having is that the Aggregate (sum) I get is only for those value of the Price_Each that are displayed in Rows in the DBgrid that are shown. So that Sum is incorrect. When I Scroll the DBGrid to bring the other rows into the View, then the Sum is Updated and then correct.

I want the Sum to be calculated for all rows in the Dataset and not just those rows visible in the DGrid?

The reason why I am using Calculated Fields is that there is some further Logic that I use to calculate the price and I would not be able to do this in an SQL statement that fetches the data.

I there any way to do this?

NOTE: I have already tried setting FetchOptions to fmAll and it did not work. Still I have to scroll the Grid ?

Comment: The default fetching mode is `fmOnDemand`, which fetches rows only when you scroll down the grid. Setting the `FetchOptions.Mode` property to `fmAll` should workaround your problem (as it fetches all the rows when the dataset is opened).

Comment: Note that changing the `FetchOptions.Mode` will  solve your problem, but you're going to hate the grid's performance if your dataset is large (simply because of the fact it fetches all of the rows). It's also going to mean a lot more data travels across your network connection from the server to the client.

Comment: @Ken, true, but there's not much to choose from. If you want to calculate something over all tuples on the client side, you just have to fetch them all.

Comment: @TLama: Yep. Just wanted to note the performance issues. I've almost always found a way to do this sort of thing on the server side so that it can be done in SQL (even if it involves temp tables) with very large datasets.

Comment: @KenWhite I would also use relational database for solving this. I would create a seperate relational table which would only store two fields (master key and Price_Each). This would allow realatively easy way to retrive that data to client without consuming of much network badwitch. And best thing is that this could be done independantly of DBGrid so it would not affect it's perfmance.

Comment: I have tried setting the Fetch Option to FmAll. Still did not work. I still have to scroll the grid. Note there are around 35 rows, so performance is not a great issue.

Comment: That should work. Have you tried to set it for the component with default settings (e.g. in a plain vanilla project) ? Forget the calculated fields, we should get all the touples to your application first.

Comment: I have created a new vanilla project with some rows in a table with a Persistent column called Quantity.I aggregate this column and result is correct (i my case 26). Now I have introduced an fkInternalCalc field NewQuantity. In The OnCalcFields event of the FDQuery, I have added the Code:

Comment: I have created a new vanilla project with some rows in a table with one Persistent column called Quantity.I aggregate this column called SumOfQuantity=SUM(Quantity) and displayed the aggregate field SumOfQuantity in a DBEdit and result is correct (i my case 26). Now I have added an fkInternalCalc field to FDQuery called NewQuantity. In The OnCalcFields event of the FDQuery, I have added the Code:
 
procedure TForm1.FDQueryCalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
    DataSet.FieldByName('NewQuantity').AsInteger := DataSet.FieldByName('Quantity').AsInteger;
end;

Comment: Now I Added a new Aggregate field, called SumOfNewQuantity = SUM(NewQuantity).

I displayed this SumOfNewQuantity is a DBEdit and it displays 1. This is not what I require.

It appears that OnCalFields in Only fired when the data needs to be displayed in an visual Control.

I also changed the FetchMode to fmAll. It did not make any difference.